# Calculate the Joint Probability Density Function given X and Y.

Tags: probability, statistics, functions, probability-distributions, random-variables

Given 
\begin{equation}
X = \sqrt{-2\ln(U_1)}\cos(2\pi U_2);\quad Y = \sqrt{-2\ln(U_1)}\sin(2\pi U_2)\end{equation}
where random variables $U_1, U_2$ have the continuous uniform distribution $U(0,1)$ and are independent of eachother.

I want to calculate the Joint probability density function.

I'm just not too sure how to start the solution.

I have that $$f(x,y) = P(X=x, Y=y)$$ and $$f(x,y) = P(Y=y|X=x)p(X=x)$$

I'm not too sure how to get something out of this formula and would just like a bit of help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $U$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$ and $f$ is strictly monotonically increasing, $f(U)$ is distributed with cumulative distribution function $f^{-1}$. Relating $U_1$ and $U_2$ to the polar coordinates $R,\Phi$ corresponding to $X$ and $Y$ yields $U_1=\mathrm e^{-\frac12R^2}$ and $U_2=\frac{\Phi}{2\pi}$. Thus $\Phi$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,2\pi]$, and $R$ has cumulative distribution function $1-\mathrm e^{-\frac12R^2}$ and thus probability distribution function $R\mathrm e^{-\frac12R^2}$. Transforming the joint density $\frac1{2\pi}R\mathrm e^{-\frac12R^2}$ to cartesian coordinates (using the Jacobian $R$) yields the joint density $\frac1{2\pi}\mathrm e^{-\frac12(X^2+Y^2)}$, which shows that $X$ and $Y$ are independent Gaussian random variables with densities $\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\mathrm e^{-\frac12X^2}$ and $\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\mathrm e^{-\frac12Y^2}$, respectively.